# What software can I use to draw diagrams and graphs?

Tags: software-recommendation, diagram

[image]

I tried to draw like this picture but failed. I used [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/).

What can I use to help draw it? I'm using Ubuntu, so software that runs on Unix operating systems would be preferred.

Comment: Inkscape perhaps? http://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 2):

### This isn't the sort of thing you *draw* so much as *generate*.

You could draw it with any vector app (such as Joonas' Inkscape recommendation). But, you're probably looking for something with better mathematical accuracy than that.

I think what you're after is something generated by a computational app. You could export the generated graphic to style in Inkscape, if you wanted to embellish/annotate it. I've been provided with such graphics but I've never had to build them myself. Hopefully someone will chime in with a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/).

> GeoGebra is free and multi-platform dynamic mathematics software for
>   all levels of education that joins geometry, algebra, tables,
>   graphing, statistics and calculus in one easy-to-use package.

The [Mathematics SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=math-software%20drawing%20is:question) has quite a few similar questions you might find useful. A search for "graphing" and "bell curves" might take you to one that can help. If you can't find any, we can migrate this question to them.